# How do you free a parent memory in an EXEC call in Minix?

Tags: c, memory-management, minix

In an EXEC call, I am looking to allow bigger "child process" by making memory through deleting Parent processes's memory.

I am using MINIX 3.2 and am planning to modify `exec.c` to call a modified version of `alloc_new_mem` in `alloc.c`

Here is the source code for alloc.c - 
https://github.com/minix3/minix/blob/master/servers/vm/alloc.c

Looking for pointers.

OS: MINIX3
File: alloc.c

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to free the parent's memory so you would have more *physical* memory for the child? Or are you looking to increase the max VMEM for the child process?

Comment: Surely that would fall over as soon as the child process exits and the waiting parent gets to run?

Answer (score 1):

In the parent process you can simply return without waiting for the child process, so child process will be reparented to init and parent address space will be freed. This doesnt involve any hacks in the kernel.